# es6 syntax for factory

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Could someone please explain how the following es6 code is a factory.

```
const createChat = ({
  id = 0,
  msg = '',
  user = 'Anonymous',
  timeStamp = 1472322852680
} = {}) => ({
  id, msg, user, timeStamp
});
```

Comment: where did you get this code from? The syntax itself is completely invalid

Comment: @CarlMarkham Nope, it works fine.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ericelliott/97ad722d1f65484752ced4cdcc145040#file-chat-reducer-factories-js    https://medium.com/javascript-scene/10-tips-for-better-redux-architecture-69250425af44#.kqscvptf2

Comment: Might help you understand it: https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=const%20createChat%20%3D%20(%7B%0A%20%20id%20%3D%200%2C%0A%20%20msg%20%3D%20%27%27%2C%0A%20%20user%20%3D%20%27Anonymous%27%2C%0A%20%20timeStamp%20%3D%201472322852680%0A%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D)%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20id%2C%20msg%2C%20user%2C%20timeStamp%0A%7D)%3B

Comment: This is just clever, yet obfuscated.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y7mb6jsp/

Comment: Why the down votes guys?

Comment: apologies, need to learn es6 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the values you see (`0`, `''`, `Anonymous`, `1472322852680`) are the default values. They would normally be extracted from the passed in object but if they don't exist these are what will be used in their place. This is [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).

The `=> ({...})` is shorthand to return the value (notice there is no `return` statement). So here it is returning an object with the passed in `id`, `msg`, `user`, and `timeStamp` unless those values aren't passed in. It is accomplishing this by using [destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

https://jsfiddle.net/y7mb6jsp/

Comment: Your answer cleared this up for me. The returned object is a new instance simply by virtue of the curly brace syntax of the return value. new Object. It is a bit confusing if you are still learning es6. Thanks for the explanation, this was helpful.

Comment: @hally9k There aren't any instances. The function just returns a plain object.

Comment: Yes it's an object, which is a new instance containing the primitives that were passed into the factory function, right? The curly brace syntax instantiates a new object, right?